# Sticky position not works as expected. works as buggy

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am trying to use the stick position with my header part. on scroll it works with couple of side move. then the header hides. it should be always in the top for my requirement. i have give z-index as well in higher value. any one help me to understand the issue.

HTML:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navi">Navigation</div>
  <header>Header goes here</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child1">Chile-1</div>
    <div class="child2">Chile-2</div>
    <div class="child3">Chile-3</div>
    <div class="child4">Chile-4</div>
    <div class="child4">Chile-5</div>
    <div class="child4">Chile-6</div>
    <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
}

.navi {
  border: 2rem solid lightpink;
}

header {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container > div {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.child4 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

[Live demno](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-s62fu8?file=styles.css)

Comment: Try setting `.wrapper` and `.container` height as `auto` ..

Comment: @SundaraMoorthyAnandh - works fine. if you have the reason to share please add in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when adding 100% height to  `.wrapper` and `.container`, the height get computed as below picture (838px in my case).. and when scroll crosses 838px, the header looses the `sticky` property.. when you set to `auto`, height will be computed automatically (adding all the divs' height) and it works expected..

height as 100%
[image: height: 100%]

height as auto
[image: height: auto]

Answer (score 0):

```css
 html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
    }

    .navi {
      border: 2rem solid lightpink;
    }

    header {
      top: 0;
      padding: 1rem;
      z-index: 100;
      position: sticky;
      background-color: gray;
    }

    .container>div {
      padding: 30px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    .child1 {
      background-color: brown;
    }

    .child2 {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .child3 {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .child4 {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navi">Navigation</div>
    <header>Header goes here</header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child1">Chile-1</div>
      <div class="child2">Chile-2</div>
      <div class="child3">Chile-3</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-4</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-5</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-6</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
      <div class="child4">Chile-7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try this one it's working perfectly.